# How to conect entity(domain layer) and model(data layer) using BloC+Freezed

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc, freezed, flutter-freezed

I'm trying to learn how to follow a clean feature-first architecture using Bloc and Freezed.

From what I've seen, I should have inside the Domain layer, an entity class declaring only its properties for the presentation layer to use, and in the Data layer, I should have a DTO of this class that's responsible for implementing the FromJson methods and whatever I might need when getting the data from the dataSources and parse it to an entity.

My questions are:

1- To which  of these classes (if not both) do I create the freezed code?

2-How do I connect the entity and the model when using the repository, should I create "fromEntity, toEntity" methods or something alike? And if such methods were to be required, can I create them with Freezed?

I'm working with this entity class:

```
class NoteEntity{
  final String title;
  final String description;

  NoteEntity({required this.title, required this.description});
}
```

I was using it with freezed like this:

```
@freezed
class NoteEntity with _$NoteEntity {
      const factory NoteEntity({
        required String title,
        required String description,
      }) = _NoteEntity;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when we talk about an `architecture`, it will lead to decision making based on our needs in the application by following to the architecture pattern.

1. `freezed` is a plugin to generate classes. like `copyWith` `toString`, `operator ==` etc.
   so Basically you can use for both layer.  you can generate the classes construtor without typing manually.

again.... its about decision-making: in my case, I usually use the freezed only on domain layer. because i dont really need that on my data layer.

---

2. yes, you can create manually `fromEntity` and `toEntity` in your domain model

- **domain layer**:

```
@freezed
class NoteEntityDomain with _$NoteEntityDomain  {
      const factory NoteEntityDomain ({
        required String title,
        required String description,
      }) = _NoteEntity;

  // fromentity
  factory NoteEntityDomain.fromEntity(NoteEntity data) {
     return NoteEntityDomain(
       title: data.title,
       description: data.description
     )
   }
 // to entity method here
}
```

---

Comment: I see, so, the idea of the domain class, Is to define all the logic I might need to map the data from the datasources and then return it to the domain layer as an entity, as well as mapping the entity itself into data that can be used in the domain layer ?